# Drawing the tangent curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could you help me make my figure to look like this one?:
[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style = thick,
            xlabel={ $x$ reserves},
            ylabel={ $y$ reserves},
            x label style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)}, anchor=north},
            y label style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)}, anchor=south, rotate=90},
            xmin=0.5, xmax=5,
            ymin=0.1, ymax=1,
            ticks=none,
            enlargelimits=false,
            clip=false,
            %
            domain=1:5,
            samples=50,
            no marks
            ]
            \addplot [black,thick]{1/x};
            
            \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label={45:{$(x_b,y_b)$}}] (a) at (6/5,5/6) {};
            \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label={45:{$(x_m,y_m)$}}] (b) at (2,1/2) {};
            \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label={45:{$(x_a,y_a)$}}] (c) at (4,1/4) {};
            
            \draw[ densely dotted] (a) -- (a |- b);
            \draw[black] (a |- b) -- (b) node[pos=.33, below] {$x_r$};
            
            \draw[ densely dotted] (c) -- (b |- c);
            \draw[black] (b |- c) -- (b) node[pos=.33, left] {$y_r$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: MWE has no tangent curve attempt. You have the function, and the point, so you can compute the slope.

Comment: The labels for Yours MWE dont have relations with the graph shown. In any case the equation of the tangent is 'y=-0.0625*x+0.5'. You can add this equation to yours plots to complete the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier to draw the pieces of this figure directly with Ti*k*Z. For ease of adjusting, I made definitions of the x-coordinates of the two points at the beginning of the tikzpicture.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{dot/.style={fill, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4pt}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=5/\x; df(\x)=(f(\x+.01)-f(\x-.01))/.02;}, font=\small]
    \def\xone{1.8} % x-coordinate of point 1
    \def\xzero{3.8} % x-coordinate of point 0
    \draw (0,5)node[left]{$R_{\beta}$}--(0,0)--(5.5,0)node[below]{$R_{\alpha}$}; % axis
    \draw[very thick, orange] (1,{f(1)}) node[below right]{$R_{\alpha}R_{\beta}=k$}--plot[domain=1:5] (\x,{f(\x)}); % curve
    \draw[densely dashed](\xone,0)node[below]{$R_{\alpha}1$}|-(0,{f(\xone)})node[left]{$R_{\beta}1$};
    \draw[densely dashed](\xzero,0)node[below]{$R_{\alpha}0$}|-(0,{f(\xzero)})node[left]{$R_{\beta}0$};
    \draw([shift={(-2,{-2*df(\xzero)})}]\xzero,{f(\xzero)})--([shift={(1.5,{1.5*df(\xzero)})}]\xzero,{f(\xzero)}); % tangent line
    \draw(\xone,{f(\xone)})node[dot, label={[label distance=-4pt]45:Post trade}]{}--(\xzero,{f(\xzero)})node[dot, label={[label distance=-4pt]45:Pre trade}]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Below is an example where x₁ is set to 1.3 and x₀ is set to 3.2. You can adjust the length of the tangent line by changing the `shift` options. `-2` extends 2 units left and `1.5` extends 1.5 units right.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A simple manual approach would be to add these lines, just before your `addplot`

```
% slope at 2 is -1/4, so (1, 1/2+1/4) -- (3, 1/2-1/4) will be tangent
\draw[blue] (1, 1/2+1/4) -- (3, 1/2-1/4);

% slope at 4 is -1/16, so (3, 1/4+1/16) -- (5, 1/4-1/16) will be tangent
\draw[red] (3, 1/4+1/16) -- (5, 1/4-1/16);
```

compiling the MWE with these additions produces this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use `declare function` and to compute numerical derivatives. Of course, the numerical derivative can be replaced with the analytic function in this case. `declare function` can also be used to define `x_a`, `x_m` and `x_b`. That way you only need to change things once and not at various positions of the code. The tangent can be defined in this manner as well. The result is something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=1/\x;
            dx=0.01;
            fprime(\x)=(f(\x+dx)-f(\x-dx))/(2*dx);
            tangent(\x,\y)=f(\y)+fprime(\y)*(\x-\y);
            xb=6/5;xm=2;xa=4;
            }]
        \begin{axis}[%
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style = thick,
            xlabel={ $x$ reserves},
            ylabel={ $y$ reserves},
            x label style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)}, anchor=north},
            y label style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)}, anchor=south, rotate=90},
            xmin=0.5, xmax=5,
            ymin=0.1, ymax=1,
            ticks=none,
            enlargelimits=false,
            clip=false,
            %
            domain=1:5,
            samples=50,
            no marks
            ]
            \addplot [black,thick]{f(x)};
            \addplot [blue,thick,domain=xa-2:xa+1.2]{tangent(x,xa)};
            \addplot [purple,thick,domain=xm-1:xm+1]{tangent(x,xm)};
            \addplot [red,thick,domain=xb-0.25:xb+0.25]{tangent(x,xb)};

            \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label={45:{$(x_b,y_b)$}}] (a) at (xb,{f(xb)}) {};
            \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label={45:{$(x_m,y_m)$}}] (b) at (xm,{f(xm)}) {};
            \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label={45:{$(x_a,y_a)$}}] (c) at (xa,{f(xa)}) {};
            
            \draw[ densely dotted] (a) -- (a |- b);
            \draw[black] (a |- b) -- (b) node[pos=.33, below] {$x_r$};
            
            \draw[ densely dotted] (c) -- (b |- c);
            \draw[black] (b |- c) -- (b) node[pos=.33, left] {$y_r$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using [tzplot](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone} 

\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
\settzdotsize{4pt}
\tzhelplines(0,0)(5,5)
\tzaxes*(0,0)(5,5.5){$R_\alpha$}[b]{$R_\beta$}[l]
\def\Fx{5/\x}
\tzfn[very thick,orange]\Fx[5:1]{$R_\alpha R_\beta=k$}[br,orange]
\tzvXpointat*{Fx}{1.8}(P0){Post trade}[ar]
\tzvXpointat*{Fx}{3.8}(P1){Pre trade}[ar]
\tzline(P0)(P1)
\tztangent{Fx}(P1)[1.8:5.3]
\tzproj[dashed](P0){$R_\alpha0$}{$R_\beta0$}
\tzproj[dashed](P1){$R_\alpha1$}{$R_\beta1$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```